# Writing function restrictions more efficiently

Tags: function-construction, code-review

I define the two functions:

```
f[p_] := 
  {{p[[1]], p[[2]], p[[3]]}, {p[[4]], p[[5]], p[[6]]}, 
   {p[[7]], p[[8]], p[[9]]}, {p[[10]], p[[11]], p[[12]]}, 
   {p[[13]], p[[14]], p[[15]]}, {p[[16]], p[[17]], p[[18]]}, 
   {p[[19]], p[[20]], p[[21]]}} /; 
      {{p[[1]], p[[2]], p[[3]]}, {p[[4]], p[[5]], p[[6]]}, 
       {p[[7]], p[[8]], p[[9]]}, {p[[10]], p[[11]], p[[12]]}, 
       {p[[13]], p[[14]], p[[15]]}, {p[[16]], p[[17]], p[[18]]}, 
       {p[[19]], p[[20]], p[[21]]}}.ConstantArray[1, {3, 7}] == 
         ConstantArray[1, {7, 7}];

g[p_] := 
  {{p[[1]], p[[2]], p[[3]]}, {p[[4]], p[[5]], p[[6]]}, 
   {p[[7]], p[[8]], p[[9]]}, {p[[10]], p[[11]], p[[12]]}, 
   {p[[13]], p[[14]], p[[15]]}, {p[[16]], p[[17]], p[[18]]}, 
   {p[[19]], p[[20]], p[[21]]}} /;
     p[[1]] == 0 || p[[1]] == 1 /; 
     p[[2]] == 0 || p[[2]] == 1 /; 
     p[[3]] == 0 || p[[3]] == 1 /; 
     p[[4]] == 0 || p[[4]] == 1 /;
     p[[5]] == 0 || p[[5]] == 1 /; 
     p[[6]] == 0 || p[[6]] == 1 /; 
     p[[7]] == 0 || p[[7]] == 1 /; 
     p[[8]] == 0 || p[[8]] == 1 /; 
     p[[9]] == 0 || p[[9]] == 1 /; 
     p[[10]] == 0 || p[[10]] == 1 /; 
     p[[11]] == 0 || p[[11]] == 1 /; 
     p[[12]] == 0 || p[[12]] == 1 /; 
     p[[13]] == 0 || p[[13]] == 1 /; 
     p[[14]] == 0 || p[[14]] == 1 /; 
     p[[15]] == 0 || p[[15]] == 1 /; 
     p[[16]] == 0 || p[[16]] == 1 /; 
     p[[17]] == 0 || p[[17]] == 1 /; 
     p[[18]] == 0 || p[[18]] == 1 /; 
     p[[19]] == 0 || p[[19]] == 1 /; 
     p[[20]] == 0 || p[[20]] == 1 /; 
     p[[21]] == 0 || p[[21]] == 1;
```

Both funcions take a vector $p$ as argument. The $f(p)$ function makes a $7 \times 3$ matrix where the sum of each row must be one. The $g(p)$ function makes a $7 \times 3$ matrix where the value of the vector $p$ must be binary numbers.

The code works, but I am sure that must be a way more efficiently to write it. I would be very grateful if someone would help or advise me.

Comment: Does Partition[p,3] do what you want for f[p]?

Comment: My advice on this is: Don't use `Condition` to do the checking. Check the arguments in the body of the function and emit a message and return the function unevaluated it the restrictions are violated. That way you can use the full functional power of Mathematica for checking -- you can write the code so it doesn't need to know size of the array.

Comment: Thanks @m_goldberg, I will looking at how to do it. After define correctly these two functions I want to maximize a system with the matrices. So your comment is very helpful to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are versions of `f` and `g` that do their testing internally. They return unevaluated if their arguments don't meet the imposed restrictions. They are also more general that the functions you defined in that they allow the shape of the matrix returned to be specified. I have made 7 rows and 3 columns the defaults, so my functions behave like yours when row and column size are not specified.

```
f[p : {_?NumericQ ..}, rows_Integer: 7, cols_Integer: 3] :=\
  Module[{m},
    m = ArrayReshape[p, {rows, cols}];
    If[m.ConstantArray[1, {cols, rows}] == ConstantArray[1, {rows, rows}],
      m,
      Defer[f[p, rows, cols]]]]

g[p : {_Integer ..}, rows_Integer: 7, cols_Integer: 3] :=
  Module[{m},
    m = Pick[p, p, 0 | 1];
    If[m != p, Defer[g[p, rows, cols]], ArrayReshape[p, {rows, cols}]]]
```

Tests

```
f[{.5, .5, 0, 1, 1/3, 2/3}, 3, 2]
```

> `{{0.5, 0.5}, {0, 1}, {1/3, 2/3}}`

```
f[{.5, .5, 1, 1, 1/3, 2/3}, 3, 2]
```

> `f[{0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 1/3, 2/3}, 3, 2]`

```
SeedRandom[42]; vec = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, 21]
```

> `{0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}`

```
g[vec]
```

> `{{0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}`

```
g[{0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0}]
```

> `g[{0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0}, 7, 3]`

```
g[{1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}, 2, 5]
```

> `{{1, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 0}}`

Note that in the last example, `g` pads the 2nd row of the result with 0 to produce a 2 x 5 array from a vector of 9 elements.

#### Update

When defining `f` above, I used your test for determining that the sum of each row is 1 without thinking about it. However, I have had second thoughts and recommend using `Total` to make the test. Like so:

```
f[p : {_?NumericQ ..}, rows_Integer: 7, cols_Integer: 3] :=
   Module[{m},
     m = ArrayReshape[p, {rows, cols}];
     If[Total[m, {2}] == ConstantArray[1, rows], m, Defer[f[p, rows, cols]]]]
```

The updated version of `f` is both simpler and more efficient than my original one.

Comment: Thank you very much @m_goldberg, I hope that Mathematica give me the solution (in function of a variable) from my maximization problem. Do you think that using an "if" in the function f doesn't be a problem to Mathematica's solvers?

Comment: @hllspwn. No way for me to tell what problem you will have with solvers without knowing which solvers you are referring to and how `f` will enter into your use of them. I say try it and see what happens. If you run into to trouble, ask a new, specific question about the problem that showed up.

Comment: Just a small comment: the pattern `_?NumericQ ..` is can also be written slightly more naturally as `__?NumericQ`. Or am I missing some subtle distinction here?

Comment: @SjoerdSmit. No, you are not missing anything. I've just gotten into the (bad) habit of writing it in the way I did.